# DirectX Overlay inside a Window

Tags: windows, graphics, directx, overlay

I need to be able to set an overlayed graphics area (via DirectX/DirectDraw methods) in any place on the screen, or at least to use it inside a windowed area. Anyone was able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a ["Layered Window"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx). Here is [an example](http://www.dhpoware.com/demos/layeredWindows.html) which shows how to do layered windows with DirectX (and OpenGL).

A Layered Window will let you make your normal window frame transparent (or semi-transparent) so that the content you draw will appear to "float" above the desktop and other windows.

Answer (score 1):

We recently created a similar application where we used C# for all GUI stuff, and DirectX for fast 3D inside a window. C# was excellent for rapid GUI development, but GDI+ was not fast enough for our program. So we were overriding the WndPrc function in a Panel inside our C# window, and transfered all control of mouse events and painting to the C++ dll. The result was smooth and let us combine all aspects of rapid application development together with a complex 3D backend.